# C++ - No se imprime un mesaje en ciclo while

Tags: c++

Estoy comenzando con el lenguaje C++, y me gustaría saber por qué no se muestra la salida de pantalla de esta línea de código
`cout<<"valor inválido"<<"\n";`. Sé que es algo muy simple pero no logro entender porque no se muestra la salida, si cuando no cumple la condición si me solicita un valor.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ll long long
using namespace std;

int main(){
  ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
  cin.tie(0);
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  while(n%2!=0||n<4){
    cout<<"valor inválido"<<"\n";
    cin>>n;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

El problema es que se va almacenando la salida, hasta que pongo un número correcto y se imprime todos los mensajes de advertencia.

```
5
5
5
5
4
valor inválido
valor inválido
valor inválido
valor inválido
```

Me gustaría que se imprima en cada ciclo cuando ingreso un número incorrecto.

```
5
valor inválido
5
valor inválido
5
valor inválido
5
valor inválido
4
```

**Actualización**

Al parecer el problema tiene que ver con estas líneas:

```
ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
cin.tie(0);
```

Leí en un libro que estas líneas me permiten optimizar el input del programa. Si alguien me puede dar más información sería genial.

PD: si remplazo `"\n"` con `endl`, el programa funciona correctamente.

Comment: ¿Qué se considera como valor válido?

Comment: En este caso solo quería mostrar cuando es inválido, en el caso que sea válido sale del while y continua el programa.

Answer (score 2):

Estas tratando de hacer la comparación en el bucle, necesitas un IF dentro del while y que el while se detenga cuando el número sea valido. Algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    bool x=true;
    while(x){
         cout<<"Ingresa un número"<<"\n";
         cin>>n;
         if(n%2!=0||n<4){
             cout<<"valor inválido"<<"\n";
         }else{
             cout<<"valor válido"<<"\n";
             x=false;
         }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Si notas la variable X es la que controla si el bucle termina o no y el IF hace la comparación.